# SQL Server - use count function with intersect

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, select

How to count the result of this query?

```
SELECT id FROM table1 where  col1 like '%abcd%'
intersect
SELECT id from table2 where col2 like '%efgh%'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
 SELECT id FROM table1 where  col1 like '%abcd%'
 intersect
 SELECT id from table2 where col2 like '%efgh%'
) I
```

Where `I` is an alias for the 'derived' table. It doesn't do anything important in this instance, but needs to be there for SQL to recognize the syntax - otherwise, you'll get an "Incorrect syntax near ')'" error.

Comment: @doza, can you please tell me why is there I at the end of the query?

Comment: It's an alias for the 'derived' table. It doesn't do anything important in this instance, but needs to be there for SQL to recognize the syntax - otherwise you'll get an "Incorrect syntax near ')'" error.

Comment: how would you do that in derby?  I am getting a syntax error using that.  (I will check out the derby manual too).

Comment: @doza, is it also possible to get a count of the second select?

Comment: Depends what you're calling the 'second select'.. This should give you the row count from the query on table2: SELECT COUNT(*) from table2 where col2 like '%efgh%'